# Make MS Access wait a long time/ trigger at a certain time (VBA)

Tags: ms-access, triggers, vba, wait, doevents

I want to run an MS Access function only once a day at a certain time - 6 a.m. The computer (Windows 2010) runs the whole day. What is the easiest and nevertheless least ressource consuming way. E. g. I could put a loop in the VBA code of MS Access to do something (e. g. DoEvent) until it is 6 a.m. But this might slow down the computer. The computer is already busy with other tasks. Thus the way of triggering the module/ function in MS Access should be as little CPU comsuming as possible. Anyone who could help, please?

Answer (score 1):

Use the *task scheduler* to run the application and specify a *macro name* on the command line (see on-line help for instructions).

Answer (score 1):

...you could also name your macro AutoExec and it will run every time the MS Access database is opened.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Task Scheduler to the rescue!!

https://www.howtogeek.com/123393/how-to-automatically-run-programs-and-set-reminders-with-the-windows-task-scheduler/

[image]

[image]